# Mobile web apps with Angular.dart

Tags: cordova, mobile, dart, angular-dart

I have a web application built with AngularDart. Now I want to transform it to a mobile web application with Cordova (so it will be available for Android and iPhone).

I've cloned official angularDart tutorial and moved Chapter 2 to Cordova. I get this error:

`Bad state: Cannot use origin without a scheme: file:///home/cinan/dartdevelopment/test2/platforms/browser/www/index.html`

The main problem is the application doesn't run from a http://... location but from file://...
How can AngularDart application run as a mobile web app?

I'm running Dart 1.7 SDK and AngularDart 1.0.

**UPDATE:**

This looks like a near-future solution: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/1557

Comment: have you tried it again since this issue is now fixed?

Comment: yes, it's working properly now, file:// schema is supported